# Using the 'document' function in XSLT, how do you get the value from the contents of the referenced document which is XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

Right now I call an external webservice and store its response (XML) as a variable like this (using XSL 2.0):

```
<xsl:variable name="ReturnMICRFormatDocument">
   <xsl:value-of select="document($ReturnMICRFormatFullURL)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

I then try to read values from specific elements of the returned document's XML:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$ReturnMICRFormatDocument/Bank/BankName"/>
```

... but it yields no value. Example of the returned XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Bank xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RoutingNumber xmlns="">121000248</RoutingNumber>
    <BankName xmlns="">WELLS FARGO BANK</BankName>
    <FormatMatches xmlns="">
        <FormatMatch MatchType="HARD" AccountLength="13">
            <CheckMICRFormat>@121000248@XCCCCCCCCCCCCC*XXXXX</CheckMICRFormat>
            <DepositMICRFormat>@518200392@XCCCCCCCCCCCCC*XXXXX</DepositMICRFormat>
        </FormatMatch>
    </FormatMatches>
</Bank>
```

Thanks for any assistance here!

Comment: Did you remove the XML namespace (`xmlns=""`) for the example?

Comment: No the namespace was blank in the XML response.

Comment: I’ll try the method you mentioned @Daniel Haley

Comment: @daniel-haley I tried your suggestion and still does not return a value.  I also tried `<xsl:value-of select="$ReturnMICRFormatDocument/*:Bank/*[namespace-uri()='' and local-name()='BankName'][1]"/>` with no result.  When I just request `<xsl:value-of select="$ReturnMICRFormatDocument"/>` the result is just plain text (not XML)...

`WELLS FARGO BANK
       @121000248@XCCCCCCCCCCCCC*XXXXX
       @518200392@XCCCCCCCCCCCCC*XXXXX`

Comment: Don't try to guess what an instruction does from its name! `xsl:value-of` constructs a text node, in this case the value of the text node is the string value of the document you have read, which consists of all the text in the document after stripping the markup.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you, that makes perfect sense as I was making such an assumption with value-of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `<xsl:variable name="doc2" select="document($url)"/>` or, if you really want `xsl:variable` with a sequence constructor inside, use `xsl:copy-of`, not `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: Thank you @martin-honnen and @MichaelKay... `xsl:copy-of` solved my problem.

Comment: @jag959, fine, but `<xsl:variable name="ReturnMICRFormatDocument" select="document($ReturnMICRFormatFullURL)"/>` suffices and doesn't create two copies of the document you load with the `document` function.

Comment: Did not notice the xsl:value-of in the xsl:variable. Nice catch.